# Getting an error with Openpyxl with Kivy

Tags: kivy, python-3.4, openpyxl

I'm trying to use some my python code I've written using IPython on Kivy, but I'm getting an error that says it cannot import name BUILTIN_FORMATS, which is called from the styleable.py within openpyxl.
BTW I used:

```
   import openpyxl as xl
```

It works perfectly fine when I run the code within IPython.
Does anyone know how I can fix this.

EDIT: I've already tried reinstalling openpyxl with pip.
EDIT2: I'm on windows 7, and here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl
import requests
import openpyxl as xl
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import Counter
from lxml import html
#function to load the table form the excel file corresponding to the passed sheet name
def loadTable(sheetName):
    lotteryData = pd.ExcelFile("Lottery databases.xlsx") #grabs and loads the file into memory
    df = lotteryData.parse(sheetName) #loads the data table form the corresponding sheetName into the df data frame
    return df

#function to display the table
def showTable(table):
    #get the number of rows the table has
    no_of_rows = len(table.index)
    #display the table

    return table.head(no_of_rows)

#function to display pie charts of a specific column within the database
#table is the database that the function will be working with
#and column is a numberical vaule of which column to get the data from
def printPieChart(table, column):
    if column == 6:
        columnList = table.iloc[:, -1:].values.T.ravel()
    else:
        columnList = table.iloc[:, (column - 7): (column - 6)].values.T.ravel()
    countedList = Counter(columnList)

    #set up the size of the pie chart
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10, 10])
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    cmap = plt.cm.prism

    #input variables for pie function
    slices = [float(v) for v in countedList.values()]
    colors = cmap(np.linspace(0., 1., len(slices)))
    labels = [float(k) for k in countedList]
    columnHeaders = list(table.columns.values)

    #the pie chart
    pie_wedge_collection = ax.pie(slices, colors = colors, labels = labels, labeldistance = 1.05, autopct = '%1.1f%%')
    #get rid of the black outlines between the wedges and around the pie
    for pie_wedge in pie_wedge_collection[0]:
        pie_wedge.set_edgecolor('white')
    ax.set_title(columnHeaders[column + 1])
    #can't display a Legends as there's too many for plt.legends() too handle
    #return pyplot.pie([float(v) for v in countedList.values()], labels = [float(k) for k in countedList])

def updateDatabase():
    wb = xl.load_workbook("Lottery databases.xlsx") #load the workbook into memory

    #list of the sheet names within the workbook
    sheetnames = ["SuperLotto", "MegaMillions", "Powerball"]
    days = ["Tue. ", "Wed. ", "Fri. ", "Sat. "] #days the draws on done on
    #list of the webpages to use grab the new draws
    webPages = ['http://www.calottery.com/play/draw-games/superlotto-plus/winning-numbers', 'http://www.calottery.com/play/draw-games/mega-millions/winning-numbers', 'http://www.calottery.com/play/draw-games/powerball/winning-numbers']
    x = 3
    while x != 0:
        ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheetnames[x-1]) # which sheet to update
        rowIndex = ws.get_highest_row() # gets the highest row index in the sheet
        lastCellValue = ws.cell(row = rowIndex - 1, column = 0).value #gets the last value in the first column, draw number
        page = requests.get(webPages[x-1]) #grabs the webpage needed
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text) #puts the webpage into a tree structure to make it easy to traverse
        #get the newest draw and date from the webpage for comparasion purposes
        draw_and_date = tree.xpath('//*[@id="objBody_content_0_pagecontent_0_objPastWinningNumbers_rptPast_ctl01_lblDrawDateNumber"]/text()')
        #if the table is up to date, it will move on to the next table else it will update it 
        y = int(draw_and_date[0][-4:]) - int(lastCellValue) # checks to see how many draws are missing from the table
        if y == 0:
            print("The table for " + sheetnames[x-1] + " is up to date.")
            x -= 1 #decrement x by 1 to move on to the next table
        else:
            #while loop to check if the table needs to be updated or not, if yes it will update it
            while y != 0:
                #grabs the draw and date of the missing draws from the table
                draw_and_date = tree.xpath('//*[@id="objBody_content_0_pagecontent_0_objPastWinningNumbers_rptPast_ctl0' + str(y) + '_lblDrawDateNumber"]/text()')
                numbers = tree.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div[3]/table/tr[" + str(y) + "]/td[2]/span/text()") #numbers
                numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers] # converts the text to integers
                numbers.sort() #sort the number from smallest to largest
                mega = tree.xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div[3]/table/tr[" + str(y) + "]/td[3]/text()") #mega number
                mega = int(mega[0]) # converts the text to integers
                #write to the file
                if sheetnames[x-1] == "MegaMillions":
                    d = 0
                else:
                    d = 1
                if int(draw_and_date[0][-4:]) % 2 == 0:
                    # if the draw date is even then the day is a Friday/Saturday
                    ws.append([int(draw_and_date[0][-4:]), (days[d+2] + draw_and_date[0][:12]), numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3], numbers[4], mega]) # print the draw date
                else:
                    # if the draw date is odd then the day is a Tuesday/Wednesday
                    ws.append([int(draw_and_date[0][-4:]), (days[d] + draw_and_date[0][:12]), numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3], numbers[4], mega])
                y -= 1 #decrement y by 1 to get the next missing draw
            print("Updated the " + sheetnames[x-1] + " table successfully!")
            x -= 1 #decrement x by 1 to move on to the next table
    wb.save("Lottery databases.xlsx") #save the workbook
    print("Saved the database Sucessfully!")
```

and so on...

Comment: Could you provide a complete code example? I can add `import openpyxl as xl` to a Kivy app and it doesn't have any issues for me with Python 3.4.3 on Ubuntu.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out how to fix in the error, so I just decided to install kivy on VM with ubuntu and go from there.